# Getting this error while installing pylint in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, pylint

What could be done to solve this issue?
Below is the error while trying to install `pylint`

```
Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\krish\envs\test\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\krish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fb16pmh5\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-3uw9a2l7' --python-tag cp36:
      ERROR: running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
      copying src\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
      copying src\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
      copying src\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
      copying src\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\setup.py", line 101, in <module>
          run_setup(with_extensions=True)
        File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\setup.py", line 71, in run_setup
          setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\krish\envs\test\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
          build_ext.run(self)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
          force=self.force)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
          return klass(None, dry_run, force)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
          CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
        File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__
          if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
      TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for wrapt
      Running setup.py clean for wrapt
    Failed to build wrapt
    Installing collected packages: wrapt, astroid, colorama, pylint
      Running setup.py install for wrapt ... error
        ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\krish\envs\test\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\krish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fb16pmh5\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cmm8ca3u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\krish\envs\test\include\site\python3.6\wrapt':
        ERROR: running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win32-3.6
        creating build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
        copying src\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
        copying src\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
        copying src\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
        copying src\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\wrapt
        running build_ext
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\setup.py", line 101, in <module>
            run_setup(with_extensions=True)
          File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\setup.py", line 71, in run_setup
            setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "c:\users\krish\envs\test\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
            return orig.install.run(self)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
            self.run_command('build')
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
            self.run_command(cmd_name)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
            build_ext.run(self)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
            force=self.force)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
            return klass(None, dry_run, force)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
            CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
          File "c:\users\krish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__
            if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
        TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command "'c:\users\krish\envs\test\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\krish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fb16pmh5\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cmm8ca3u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\krish\envs\test\include\site\python3.6\wrapt'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\krish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb16pmh5\wrapt\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got stuck on similar problem and solved it by installing wheel.

```
pip3 install wheel
pip3 install pylint
```